# Average number of words per sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dataset, which contains collection of text messages. I want to calculate the average words per sentence. But each message is in different format. ie, some messages ends with fullstop some messages not...

eg messages:

```
          Tiwary to rcb.battle between bang and kochi
          Dhawan for dc:)
          Warner to delhi.
          make it fast...
```

by using,

```
   words = messages.split() #get each words in the sentence
   leg_wrd = len(words)
```

but there is problem to find the end of sentence because it's not in similar. Then how can I identify the end of a sentence? And how to calculate the same using python 2.7.

Comment: By newline `\n` character?

Comment: `lines = data.splitlines()` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem. I would recommend to use a 3rd party library like [NTLK](https://www.nltk.org/index.html). This has a sentence tokenizer which works like this:

```
# Make sure that you have NLTK
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text = “this’s a sent tokenize test. this is sent two. is this sent three? sent 4 is cool! Now it’s your turn.”

sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(text)

print(sent_tokenize_list)
# Will output [“this’s a sent tokenize test.”, ‘this is sent two.’, ‘is this sent three?’, ‘sent 4 is cool!’, “Now it’s your turn.”]
```